# What is the name of a "role" in a family tree? / What is the name of the initial person in a family tree?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have two questions concerning family trees:

1. What is the name of the initial person in a family tree? For example, if you want to know the family tree of a certain person, you have that person in the center and then draw lines from that person referring to all of that person's relatives, ancenstors, descendants, partner  and siblings. Is it called individual?
2. What is the name of the role a certain person has in a family tree? For example a sister, mother, father, aunt, etc?

Comment: You might be better asking here http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/ chances are you'll get a better answer.

Comment: The person in the center is called ***Ego***. The names of the "roles" are called ***kinship terms***. All kinship terms in a given family tree (e.g, "maternal grandfather") are calculated by default from Ego -- i.e, *maternal grandfather **of Ego***. See [Kinship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinship).

Comment: @JohnLawler You basically answered both questions just like that! Create a separate post and I'll accept it after a couple of minutes :)

Comment: @JohnLawler Sounds like a category mistake.  "What is the name of the role that Jane has in Bill's family tree?"  "Her kinship term is sister." vs. "Her relationship is sister."

Comment: Her kinship term is "sister of Ego". It's transitive. Relationships are sometimes reciprocal ("cousin - cousin" vs "grandfather - grandchild")

Comment: @John Lawler Why did you never make an answer post?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, sources may differ in the terminology they prefer. Sometimes *subject* is used for the person whose family tree is being developed, and *relationship* is used for all of the positions (parents, siblings, aunts, uncles, cousins, etc.) to specify how the people are related to one another.

http://www.eogen.com/Relationships

Answer (score 1):

The term is **progenitor**.

> A progenitor is a person or thing from which others are descended or
>   originate. For example, it is used to refer to the ancestor who
>   started the line of a noble family.
>
> In a wider sense today it is used to refer to the person who
>   originates a movement or way of life.

Read more at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progenitor).

Comment: A progenitor only works downwards I think, while ego's relations can go in any direction.