# Title or word to describe the first, original member of a family tree

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

I'm looking for a word to signify the ancestor from which a family tree is derived. They would be the first, from whom all other family members are descended. Does such a word exist? I imagine, given the long history of creating family trees, that someone at some point decided on a word other than 'the first guy'.

Comment: see here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172749 (in the comments immediately under the question) Ego.

Comment: ... teratogen's answer. Good spot, Frank: the title only mentions the other question (naughty!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the name of a "role" in a family tree?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172749/what-is-the-name-of-a-role-in-a-family-tree)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This, I gather, is the central person when working *backwards* from an ancestor (e.g. I would be the `Ego` for a family tree starting from me and working backwards). I'm going the other way - say, what was Adam to the children of Cain and Abel, etc.

Comment: Depending on creed and level of religious belief, the answer should really be _Adam_ or _Eve_ or some similar pairing (or, in more evolutionary terms, [Mitochondrial Eve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_Eve)), since all human family trees are interlaced at least as far back as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the word "proband" used in genealogy as the person of interest when either all descendants of the person, or all ancestors of the person are being studied.

This term is also used in genetics as the person being studied who has a trait of interest that may be passed to any descendant, and may have come from any ancestor.

See also [What is the name of a "role" in a family tree?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/what-is-the-name-of-a-role-in-a-family-tree) on Genealogy and Family History Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

The word that popped into my own head was *progenitor*, which the OED gives as sense 1 the following:

> A person from whom another person, a family, or a race, is descended; an ancestor, a forefather.

One advantage of *progenitor* over *forefather* is that it works for either sex.  Well, in my opinion, at least, it does.  The words *progenitress, progenitrice,* and  *progenitrix* do exist and would in theory be available for an ancestral female, just as *ancestress* would.  But I’m not sure that the explicitly female versions of these words get much currency these days.

Answer (score 2):

Found it — the term is the *apical ancestor*. See [Wikipedia for details](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apical_ancestor).

Comment: And I learned `apical` too! :D

Comment: Which brings to mind [*apex predator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apex_predator), where a rather different sort of tree is involved.

Comment: great answer! I'd never heard 'apical' either!

Comment: apical progenerator? might be good but I doubt anyone will know what the hell it means! apical.... tendencies. apical protuberances. apical tropisms. just playing.

Answer (score 1):

I think [forefather](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Forefather) is the word you are looking for:

> - the founder of a family; "keep the faith of our forefathers"

Comment: That's the idea, but I would consider that any male along the entire depth of a family tree line could be called a forefather (are there 'foremothers'?). I was hoping for an word to signify the role.

Comment: For that matter, plenty of lines have **founders** as noted in your quote.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a man and a woman to have a family. If I am drawing up a family tree, I ought to include both.

As to the point in time to start is not a easy question to answer as it is arbitrarily defined.

I would stick with progenitor for both the man and the woman. Leaving out the woman makes it politically incorrect.

As to blood line, which is easy back to the progenitor(man).

Answer (score 1):

Antecedent

Antecedent means 'something that happened before or is the cause of what's going on now', and antecedents can be used to mean 'ancestors'.

Using 'primal antecedent' or 'primary antecedent' could work. Or 'original antecedent'. To refer to the very first  ancestor.

Antecedent

someone or something existing or happening before, especially as the cause or origin of something existing or happening later:

Charles Babbage's mechanical calculating engines were the antecedents of the modern computer.

Many people feel a great curiosity to find out about their antecedents. (note: meaning - ancestors)

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/antecedent

Comment: Can you site an example where this word is used to refer to people and not objects?  Seems kind of dehumanizing to me in the OP's context. [Oops...just clicked on your link.  There is one there!  ...Good answer +1

Comment: It is commonly used to refer to ancestors. It is not limited to objects yes the the link does specifically state that. Thanks! ☺️✨

Comment: by the way @thomj1332 I think you mean 'cite' not 'site'!!

Answer (score -1):

"Patriarch" or "matriarch" also might be of use.