# Distinguishing Counts of Ancestors

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to refer to a number of ancestors in two ways, and I need two terms or even two adjectives for "ancestors" that will distinguish one from another.

The case I am interested in is where there is pedigree collapse, where one person is an ancestor of the proband in multiple ways.

For example, the following simple pedigree of Cleopatra (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedigree_collapse))

[image]

The diagram identifies 13 ancestors.

In genealogy, the typical method of denoting ancestors is through a pedigree chart, where each generation of the chart shows both parents for each person of the previous generation and thus always grows in a binary manner, with 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ... ancestors listed at each generation. Of course, not all the ancestors are always known and some of the ancestors may repeat.

So the above Cleopatra tree will then be shown as:

```
        - Ptolemy V Epiphanes
      - Ptolemy VIII Physcon
        - Cleopatra I Syra
    - Ptolemy IX Latyros
        - Ptolemy VI Philometor
      - Cleopatra III
        - Cleopatra II
  - Ptolemy XII Auletes
        - Ptolemy V Epiphanes
      - Ptolemy VIII Physcon
        - Cleopatra I Syra
    - Cleoptra IV
        - Ptolemy VI Philometor
      - Cleopatra III
        - Cleopatra II
- Cleopatra VII Philopator
        - Ptolemy V Epiphanes
      - Ptolemy VIII Physcon
        - Cleopatra I Syra
    - Ptolemy X Alexander I
        - Ptolemy VI Philometor
      - Cleopatra III
        - Cleopatra II
  - Cleopatra V
          - Ptolemy V Epiphanes
        - Ptolemy VIII Physcon
          - Cleopatra I Syra
      - Ptolemy IX Latyros
          - Ptolemy VI Philometor
        - Cleopatra III
          - Cleopatra II
    - Berenice III
          - Ptolemy V Epiphanes
        - Ptolemy VIII Physcon
          - Cleopatra I Syra
      - Cleopatra Selene I
          - Ptolemy VI Philometor
        - Cleopatra III
          - Cleopatra II
```

This shows 38 ancestors, but there are only 13 individuals, many of whom are repeated multiple times due to the inbreeding.

My question is I want to refer to the two different counts of ancestors. So what would be the best terminology to use to say:

I have 13 __________

I have 38 __________

Comment: How about "13 unique ancestors"?

Comment: @HotLicks - Would you understand my meaning if I said I had 13 unique ancestors but 38 non-unique ancestors?

Comment: I would say 38 total.

Comment: @HotLicks - Maybe: there are 38 total ancestors made up of 13 unique individuals.

Comment: That works for me.

Comment: I’d say that 38 of the branches in my family tree are filled by just 13 unique individuals.

Comment: @Jim - A branch of a family tree is normally thought of as more than just an ancestor.

Comment: I wouldn’t say 38 total ancestors for a number of reasons. One is that to me that implies 38 unique individuals. Another is that you have many more than 38 ancestors - it just depends on how far you choose to go back.

Comment: Yeah. I originally wrote “slots” but changed it at the last minute.  Choose whatever term you like for that part.

Comment: @Jim - Good reason for not using "total". I'd choose a term, but I don't know what term to use. That's why I'm asking the question here. Hopefully to get a good answer.

Comment: That’s not what you’re asking about though. To ask that question you’d say, “what is the term for one “slot/position” in a family tree?”

Comment: Going beyond 'there are 13 ancestors' is stretching the accepted meaning of 'ancestor' unacceptably (unless there's a technical usage I'm unaware of); it will lead to confusion. I'd stick with 'There are 13 ancestors shown in this simplified genealogical chart, but they make multiple appearances (totalling 38).

Answer (score 1):

For your use, I would employ 'predecessor',

> a. A person who comes before another person in time; an ancestor, a forefather, a forebear.

For the sense of 'individual ancestors',

> I have 13 *predecessors*.

Or, similarly, I might use 'progenitor',

> 1. A person from whom another is descended; an ancestor, a forefather; a parent.

For that same sense:

> I have 13 *progenitors*.

For the more general sense of 'ancestors', understanding your use of 'ancestor' to mean 'a position in the genealogical structure', I might use 'ascendant',

> 8. *One who precedes in genealogical succession*; an ancestor; a relative in the ascending line, whether lineal, as father, mother, or collateral, as uncle, great-uncle.

So in your second example:

> I have 38 *ascendants*.

While the context may make the distinctions between the terms you use evident, it might also be advisable to make explicit the distinction between 'predecessors' or 'progenitors' in the sense of 'individual ancestors' and 'ascendants' in the sense of 'a position in the genealogical tree'.

---

Note also that, depending on the purpose or nature of the genealogy, I might use 'propositus' rather than 'proband'. This is because the sense of 'proband' is usually restricted technically, as

> *Med.* and *Genetics*.
>   The individual with whom the investigation of a family *for a genetic disorder or other inherited trait* begins; the first member of a family to be diagnosed with a hereditary disease or trait.

'Propositus', on the other hand, is not restricted in technical use to a primary ancestor considered with reference to genetic disorders or inherited traits, but is more generally applied to any individual viewed as the basis of a genealogy:

> 1. A person from whom a line of descent is derived; an individual from whom family relationships are calculated or on whom a genealogy or pedigree is based.

(All definitions from [*OED Online*](http://oed.com/). Phrase emphasis in definitions of 'ascendant' and 'proband' is mine.)

Comment: I don't see why "predecessor" or "progenitor" or "ascendant" is any better than "ancestor". The problem is not the word "ancestor" but how to distinguish the two counts of ancestors. Some suggestions in the comments indicate an adjective (e.g. total or unique) might do, but I'm looking for something that will most clearly distinguish the two types of counts and indicate the meaning.

Comment: The question uses the word "proband", maybe incorrectly, but isn't asking about its meaning. See: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184681/title-or-word-to-describe-the-first-original-member-of-a-family-tree/193028

Comment: @lkessler, you asked, I answered. As the definitions make plain, both 'progenitor' and 'predecessor' refer to ancestors without reference to genealogy or genealogical succession, while 'ascendant' does refer to position in hierarchical succession, rather than simple ancestry. Hence the accuracy of using the 'ascendant' for the 38 positions. // I don't know the thrust of your genealogy; 'propositus' is simply an offering of what may be a more precise term than 'proband' for your use, in case you weren't aware of it.